# How to find largest connected subgraph in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, subgraph

yes, like the title says, I have a social graph stored in neo4j, about 1 million nodes and 20million relationships, I want to get the the largest connected subgraph, so I can continue my work. now I write a program to do that, i use DFS() to find the largest connected subgraph.If it is tound ,I delete those not connected nodes. But it takes 3 hours.....So my question is :Is there a more effectient algorithm to find the largest connected subgraph?
Any suggestions will be helpful~Thanks!

Comment: Would you be willing to share your DFS implementation for finding the maximal subgraphs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it works fine for me:

```
START input=node:user(your lucene index)
MATCH path = input-[:YOUR_REL*1..]->m WHERE NOT(m-[:YOUR_REL]->())
RETURN path
```

and you may have a look at this [find longest path](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/neo4j/4tLVSSKnn_M)